# Angular scope not seen by children divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This is part of my controller:

```
mbpMod.controller("bookController", function($scope,api) {   
    ...
    $scope.bookTable=new BookTable();
    $scope.bookLabel="Book";
    ...
}
```

in my HTML page it works until it is like this:

```
<md-tab>
        <md-tab-label class="mbpPanel">Book</md-tab-label>   
        <md-tab-body>       
         <div flex ag-grid="bookTable.table" class="ag-mbp lowtable" ng-controller="bookController"></div>
    </md-tab-body> 
</md-tab>
```

But it doesn't work when I do this:

```
<md-tab>
    <div ng-controller="bookController">
        <md-tab-label class="mbpPanel">{{bookLabel}}</md-tab-label>   
        <md-tab-body>       
             <div flex ag-grid="bookTable.table" class="ag-mbp lowtable" ></div>                
        </md-tab-body> 
    </div> 
</md-tab>
```

I cannot put ng-controller directive in md-tab tag, as it will result in a double directive.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's md-tab. Give full code.

Comment: is angular material tab. Not mine

Comment: Pl, then mention you are using angular-material.

Comment: this should work! are you getting any error in console? just try putting controller over md-tab `<div ng-controller="bookController"><md-tab>..........</md-tab></div>`

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why it didn't work the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `md-tab`-directive is used to specify information about a tab and how the tab should look like.

When the directive is being compiled, the controller of the `md-tab`directive is executed. If you have a look at [the source code on Github](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.1.1/src/components/tabs/js/tabDirective.js#L61), you will see that the controller checks the direct children of the `md-tab` directive to retrieve the `md-tab-label` and `md-tab-body` contents.

The working example you provided us has `md-tab-label` and `md-tab-body` as a child of the `md-tab`. In the broken example, only the `div` is a child of `md-tab`, so the controller is not able to find a label and the body for the tab.

If you move the `ng-controller` declaration outside of your `md-tab` definition, it should work.